# Import datasheet iteration matlab - name to exist outside of function

Tags: matlab

So have some simple collumated data in text files named like:

`Hm_slit_01.txt...Hm_slit_21.txt; Hs_slit_01.txt...Hs_slit_23.txt;  Sm_slit_01.txt...Sm_slit_27.txt; Ss_slit_01.txt...Ss_slit_32.txt` etc...

and I need to import it as datasheets into matlab, idealy with the same name but no `.txt`.

So I have created a function that takes a prefix `Hm, Hs ...` and a final number to iterate the file naming up to. BUT it doesn't save the datasheet externally in the workplace.
Here is the code.

```
function [datasheet] = imp_vrad(prefix,numslits)
%[data] = imp_vrad(prefix,numslits)
%   imports data with filename <prefix>_slit_<##>.txt
%   to be a matlab datasheet data = <prefix>_slit_<##>
%   here ## starts from '01' and goes to 'numslits'
%   FILES MUST BE IN WORKING DIRECTORY!

for currslit=1:numslits
    if currslit < 10
        filename = [prefix '_slit_0' num2str(currslit) '.txt']; %names file
        data = [prefix '_slit_0' num2str(currslit)]; %names datasheet
    else
        filename = [prefix '_slit_' num2str(currslit) '.txt']; %names file
        data = [prefix '_slit_' num2str(currslit)]; %names datasheet
    end

    disp(['importing ' filename ' as ' data]) 
    importdata(filename);   %imports the data

end
end
```

The line in question is the last line. I have also tried `data=importdata(filename);` to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to change the scope of a variable in matlab. You can define them dynamically using eval, but that still won't get us past the scope problem.

You have two options: if the names mater to you, you could put the imported tables in a struct, akin to what `import` does; or, if you only care about the index, you could import them into an array (perhaps multidimensional).

For the former you could do something like

```
function [datasheet] = imp_vrad(prefix,numslits)
%[data] = imp_vrad(prefix,numslits)
%   imports data with filenames <prefix>_slit_<##>.txt
%   into a struct with labels <prefix>_slit_<##>
%   here ## starts from '01' and goes to 'numslits'
%   FILES MUST BE IN WORKING DIRECTORY!
%
    datasheet = struct();
    for currslit=1:numslits
        dataname = sprintf('%s_slit_%02d',prefix,currslit);
        filename = [dataname,'.txt'];

        disp(['importing ' filename ' as ' data]) 
        data = importdata(filename);   %imports the data

        datasheet.(dataname) = data;
    end

end
```

Comment: You sir, are legendary. That works a treat  - except need to change `disp(['importing ' filename ' as ' data]) ` to `disp(['importing ' filename ' as ' dataname]) ` - but this means that I can do things like: `disp(ans.Hm_slit_03.data(:,7))` to utilise particular columns from the data set :D THANKYOU!!!

Comment: Someone vote David up for me :D ?? My rep isn't high enough!!